# How can I create my own system recovery disc?

Tags: windows-7, windows, acronis-trueimage, norton-ghost, recovery-disk

I have a system already installed with the OS and applications I needed and I want to create a recovery disc for the system so that in the event there is a crash or HDD spoil I can just use this recovery disc. Like Acer's eRecovery, that can gather all of the current data on your HD (OS, programs, updates, drivers) to create a set of restore disk that will bring your system back to the exact state that it was when you create the disk.

I'm not talking about disk image but rather bootable recovery disc like Acer/Dell. Is there such tools that can help me in creating such recovery disc for my system?

Answer (score 1):

I like Acronis.  (Will never go back to Norton, just had way too many troubles with their software.)  Here you go.  It's easy.  (Tip: You might have to zoom in a bit to see.)

[image]